# Posting JSON Data WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am experiencing a strange problem when posting data to a Web API service hosted in Azure and would appreciate any insight.

I've written a pretty basic Web API service that has a controller that receives a List via a Post Method. I am posting data to this API via a console application using a client created from a `HttpClientFactory`.

When I debug this locally all works well and I have successful posted a List containing 100 elements and written this to my local database. If I switch my local Web API code to point to my Azure database it still all works well and I can receive the 100 elements without issue and write to the Azure DB instance.

When I deploy the API service to my Azure account and hook my console application to post data to it - it works perfectly with a List containing up to 45 elements, any more and the PostAsync waits for around 6 minutes and then fails with an internal server error.

So my question is why does the service go from being able to post 43 elements in around a second to failing with 44 elements, but taking 6 minutes to do so?

I should point out my List contains 100 duplicate items as I am generating the data for testing so there is nothing wrong (or different) with a particular element within the set.

T is is simple class with around 30 properties and no child elements so I am not posting a massive structure.

My thinking is this has to be a size restriction somewhere that is not taking effect on my local machine but is when I deploy to Azure. I am not by any means a Web API expert so I'm not sure where to start looking.

Some Client code (works perfectly when i <= 43):

```
List<Foo> results = new List<Foo>();

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    results.Add(new Foo() { // Populated with data - removed for brevity });
}

StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage postDataResponse = await postClient.PostAsync(myWebApiServiceURL, content);
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Foo>Post([FromBody]List<Foo> value)
{
   return value;
}
```

Web.config settings I've tried that have no effect:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"  maxRequestLength="200000000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="16384" />
```

and

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="20000000"/>
```

I've just ran a test and it doesn't work with 44 elements content length = 53278

The maximum length it works at is when my total elements are 43 content length = 48361.

NOTE: I've just ran some more tests and if I reduce the data length in some of my string properties (thereby reducing the footprint of each element) I can post more elements. Therefore it has to be a message size restriction somewhere!!

> **UPDATE - HMAC Authentication**

OK the cause is always the least expected thing that you don't document in the question. I have HMAC Authentication enabled on my API and when I remove the attribute from my controller I can post 10000 elements without issue. As soon as I enable it I am limited back down to 43.

On the client I am generating an MD5 hash of the request content as part of the header signature, this process is being repeated in the HMAC Attribute on the Web API service. If I remove this part of the signature from both my client and the service then I can post as much data as I want. The code I have commented out on the client is shown below:

```
//Checking if the request contains body, usually will be null with HTTP GET and DELETE
if (request.Content != null)
{
   byte[] content = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
   MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
   //Hashing the request body, any change in request body will result in different hash, we'll incure message integrity
   byte[] requestContentHash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
   requestContentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(requestContentHash);
}
```

The code I have commented out in the service is below:

```
byte[] hash = await ComputeHash(req.Content);

if (hash != null)
{
   requestContentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

`ComputeHash` function:

```
private static async Task<byte[]> ComputeHash(HttpContent httpContent)
{
   using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
   {
      byte[] hash = null;
      var content = await httpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
      if (content.Length != 0)
      {
        hash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
      }
        return hash;
   }
}
```

So with the above code commented out `requestContentBase64String` is always an empty string on both client and server therefore the MD5 hash of the content is not being used as part of the authentication signature.

I now have to research the root cause of this behaviour.

Comment: Try adding the aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers under appSettings in web.config. Check the length of your json and put it as a value like <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="YOUR_LENGTH"/>

Comment: @AliBaig I have tried that with `<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="20000000"/>` with no effect.

Comment: have you also tried to set maxRequestLength size?

Comment: @xszaboj yes see edit

Comment: @CSL what is the message size? with 45 and 46. You should be able to see it in fiddler or something. What is the error you get back on 46?

Comment: Is there any logging on your Azure site that could tell you what the problem "Internal Server Error" is? at least check if you are receiving the request in your controller or if it is failing before that. This might be caused by invalid data (even if it works locally), connection error from the web app to the Azure DB....

Comment: @CSL Does API fail exactly at 46th record every time? Could you reduce properties from 30 to 5, and see any difference?

Comment: @xszaboj it works when content length is 48361 (see edits)

Comment: @Win good idea,  I'll try that tomorrow. It works when content length is 48361 see edits

Comment: @zaidsafadi I will investigate tomorrow thanks, the data shouldn't be an issue as each element has exactly the same hard coded property values, if it works for one element it should work for any number.

Comment: @Win, reduced the footprint of an element and can now post more see edit

Comment: I just tried, made a quick Web API in an Azure Web App, posted 1 445 001 bytes to a controller action just like yours just fine. No configuration changes done, pure template just created with VS 2015.

Comment: Further testings shows the limit is 4 megabytes as documented, that's the default ASP.NET limit.

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/06/15/uploading-large-files-to-azure-web-apps/

Check your max post size for Azure. Depending on your configuration that could be the issue. Either change the configuration or look at reducing the post size into smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am not posting that much data (less than a megabyte) and if I remove the HMAC authentication I can post larger volumes through Azure without issue. The issue is somewhere in my implementation of the authentication attribute. I have yet to spend sufficient time investigating to come up with a root cause.